# Google checkout sandbox for buyer

Tags: asp.net, google-checkout

I am an ASP.Net Web developer and trying to create Google checkout test account. As instructions are given here https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?answer=134469 I am trying to create a Google sandbox account for a buyer. But the page contains some required fields i.e. credit card number, CVC.  How can I provide this information while I am creating a sandbox buyer account?

Answer (score 1):

Use "test" credit card numbers. See doc below for sample numbers:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Sandbox.html